# How to filter contact person for partner in OpenERP?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-8

I want to add partner's contact person and it Should filter customers contacts based on partner

I used this in xml but got nothing

```
<field name="partner_contact_id" context="{'group_by':'partner_id'}"/>
```

and my field is like all field

```
'partner_contact_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Contact Person'),
_defaults = {
    'partner_contact_id': lambda self, cr, uid, context: context.get('partner_id', False) and self.pool.get('res.partner').address_get(cr, uid, [context['partner_id']], ['invoice'])['invoice'],

}
```

I tried to fetch it using different different address for particular partner

Comment: Is this a form/tree/search view? Are you inheriting some existing model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain attribute is used to filter records. Try this:

```
<field name="partner_contact_id" domain="[('parent_id', '=', partner_id)]" />
```

It will allow only the contacts that are bound to the company in `partner_id`. And if you want to clear the contact field when the company is changed, replace the partner field with this (view xml):

```
<field name="partner_id" on_change="onchange_partner_id(partner_id, context)" ...your other attributes.../>
```

and override the onchange method in your custom model like this:

```
def onchange_partner_id(self, cr, uid, ids, part, context=None):
    res = super(MyCustomModel, self).onchange_partner_id(cr, uid, ids, part, context)
    res['value'].update({'partner_contact_id': False})
    return res
```

Comment: Thanks it's working well
but needed some code modify i have did it